# Displaying Excel data sequentially down zig zag form?

Tags: c#, excel

How can we re-arrange the data exist in column A & B by mixisng in zig-zag form to column C. Column B is 15% of Column A.
Specifically put A1 to C1, B1 to C2, A2, to C3, B2 to C4 and so forth.
Finally we get a data in a straight line form that exist in Column C.

Example the final output of column C will be as follows:

```
    A   B      C
1   10  1.5    10
2   20  3      1.5
3   30  4.5     20
4   40  6       3
5   50  7.5     30
                 4.5
                 40
                 6
                 50
                 7.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula in column C ... `=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,A1,B1)`

ROW() returns the current row number, MOD() return the modulus of the ROW divided by 2, and the IF statement basically says, if i am on an even row, use column B, and if i am on an odd row, use column A.

---

You can change the zig-zag to a zag-zig by changing the formula to either `=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,A1,B1)` or `=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,B1,A1)`

---

Try this instead ... `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS( CEILING.MATH(ROW()/2),IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,1,2)))`.

For versions of Excel prior to 2013:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(CEILING(ROW()/2,1),IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,1,2)))
```

We divide the row number by 2 and use ceiling to round it up to nearest whole number ... that means for every two rows you move down, the row in the formula only increases by 1 ... then you just have to reuse the previous formula to calculate which column to take a value from.

ADDRESS takes a row and column and gives you the appropriate cell address, which is then used by INDIRECT.

Comment: I tried using your answer but it jumps one cell. I make the question more clear and neat, check it.